# Extend local network using a DSL wireless modem as an access point

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dsl-modem, wireless-access-point

Is it possible to convert a DSL modem to an access point in order to extend your network?

I have a [Linksys WAG54G-AU](http://support.linksys.com/en-eu/support/gateways/WAG54G) on the ground floor apartment and a spare [LevelOne WBR-3460B](http://si.level1.com/levelone.php?page=prod&cat=7028) which I hope could be used as an Access Point on the second floor. My goal is to be able to extend and access the network wirlessly, I would prefer to keep the same password and SSID of the existing wireless and use the existing Ethernet cable that is on the third floor, so nothing too fancy, I would also prefer **not** to mess with other firmware if possible.

Note: The purpose of this is to extend the network from the ground floor to the second floor using an Ethernet cable and the mentioned modems/routers.

P.S.: After some research on the internet I found this post by a guy who said that he managed to do it but had some problems with the wireless of the second modem, I'm not sure what he did...--> http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f135/using-second-dsl-modem-as-access-point-543932.html

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Your WAG54G-AU is already an access point that will let you access the network wirelessly. Do you plan to wire the WBR-3460B to the WAG43G-AU? If so, what's our goal -- better WiFi coverage? You say your "goal is to be able to access the network wirlessly" -- but can't you do that already?

Comment: What I'm trying to do (an should include in the post in the first place but thought it was obvious) is extend the network with an Ethernet cable so I could access it from the second modem I have as a spare and not have to buy a new router/access point. And yes I do plan to wire them and need instructions on how to achieve this because there are certainly a few changes that need to be made in the configuration if this is possible. @hennes actually answered my question already.

Comment: Feel free to add it to the post. After all, it will make it a lot clearer and there are several other options which are also sensible. (e.g. not wiring the WBR to the Linksys, but using it as a soft of wireless repeater (think WAP without a cable) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you "WBR-3460B DSL modem" is not just a DSL modem. As you can see [in the manual](http://www.manualslib.com/download/92303/Levelone-Wbr-3460.html) it is an composite device with:

- Either a POST (A) or ISDN (B) ADSL modem
- An integrated wireless G access point, and
- A build in router.

There is no reason why you have to use the DSL part. You can use it as a WAP assuming the firmware supports it.

Do do that you need to make sure that:

1. Turn off DHCP on the device you want to use as a WAP. You want all DHCP request answered by one single device. Not two who race who can answer first and all potential conflicts of dual administration.
2. The new modem does not use the same IP as any other device in your network (esp. make sure if it not set to the same IP as your other router). Easiest way to do this: Set the modem as DHCP **client**.  (client, not service which you just disabled).

The next steps depends on your firmware and your goals:

- Do you want the 'WAP' to have the same SSID and same password as the Linksys?
- Do you want to isolate the network?
- Etc etc..

Add those goals to your post.

Should you have a goal which can not be met with the original firmware, then check out 
[dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index), [Open WRT](https://openwrt.org/), [Tomatoe](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) and similar firmwares. **Do** read their manual pages before trying any of them.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, it is OK to use multiple APs on one subnet, and assign an identical SSID to any of their WiFis? A WiFi client will not become confused when it "sees" more than one AP and tries to negotiate a connection with one or the other?